# counting non-repetitive data in data frame cell - pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'userName': {0: 'john', 1: 'amanda', 2: 'sara', 3: 'john'}, 'serialNum': {0: '[a4G, bweQ, fp_dE4]', 1:'' , 2: '[H2dw45, IfC4, bAf23g, Lkfr54-op, a3dLa]', 3: '[Tr45b, kM30, a4G, riU91]'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

*each userName is unique.
for each userName I want to count number of data in serialNum column.

my code is:

```
df['serialNum'] = df['serialNum'].str.strip('[]').str.replace("'", "").str.replace('"', '').replace('', np.nan).str.split(',').fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})



df_count = (df['serialNum'].str.len()
                .groupby(df['userName'], sort=False).sum()
     ).to_frame(name='count').reset_index()
```

my df_count data frame:

| userName | serialNum |
| --- | --- |
| john | 7 |
| amanda | 0 |
| sara | 5 |

but I don't want to count repetitive data (serialNum) for each userName and true df_count is:

| userName | serialNum |
| --- | --- |
| john | 6 |
| amanda | 0 |
| sara | 5 |

my question is: How to count without duplicate data ( in column serialNum)?

and if you have a better offer for counting the number of values in the serialNum column, please share with me.

**note:** I prefer to use pandas or numpy methods and functions instead of writing new functions or *for loop*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas-dataframe-explode) + [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-aggregate) `nunique`:

```
u_count_df = (
    df.explode('serialNum')
        .groupby('userName', sort=False).agg({'serialNum': 'nunique'})
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'serialNum': 'uCount'})
)
```

`u_count_df`:

```
  userName  uCount
0     john       6
1   amanda       0
2     sara       5
```

---

With the current setup you'll need to strip the extra whitespace off because of the way the strings are processed:

```
e = df.explode('serialNum')
e['serialNum'] = e['serialNum'].str.strip()

u_count_df = (
    e.groupby('userName').agg({'serialNum': 'nunique'})
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'serialNum': 'uCount'})
)
```

Or change the way the strings are split:

```
df['serialNum'] = (
    df['serialNum'].str.strip('[]')
        .replace({"'": '', '"': ''}, regex=True)
        .replace({'': np.NaN})
        .str.split(r'\s*,\s*')
        .fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})
)

u_count_df = (
    df.explode('serialNum')
        .groupby('userName', sort=False).agg({'serialNum': 'nunique'})
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'serialNum': 'uCount'})
)
```

`u_count_df`:

```
  userName  uCount
0     john       6
1   amanda       0
2     sara       5
```